# Getting error when serialize xml to c# class

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to serialize a XML file to C# object but I'm getting the following error:

> There is an error in XML document (1, 64).

I copy the XML file and *pasted special as xml* in the Visual studio.

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" standalone="yes"?><root><record CodUnic="G15_455262_RO6739810_2016" CodStatie="G15" DocId="1" TipDoc="Gastro" NrDoc="455262" DataDoc="2016-01-21" DataIntr="2016-01-21" NrIntr="0" Retur="0" DataAnulare="" CodFurnizor="RO6739810" DenFurnizor="SC IFANTIS GGG SRL" ValoareFaraTVA="171.91" ValoareTVA="15.47" /></root>
```

This is my generated "special class" :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace XMLCheckTool.Clase
{

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class IntrCap
{

    private rootRecord recordField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public rootRecord record
    {
        get
        {
            return this.recordField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.recordField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class rootRecord
{

    private string codUnicField;

    private string codStatieField;

    private int docIdField;

    private string tipDocField;

    private uint nrDocField;

    private System.DateTime dataDocField;

    private System.DateTime dataIntrField;

    private int nrIntrField;

    private int returField;

    private string dataAnulareField;

    private string codFurnizorField;

    private string denFurnizorField;

    private decimal valoareFaraTVAField;

    private decimal valoareTVAField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string CodUnic
    {
        get
        {
            return this.codUnicField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.codUnicField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string CodStatie
    {
        get
        {
            return this.codStatieField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.codStatieField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public int DocId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.docIdField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.docIdField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string TipDoc
    {
        get
        {
            return this.tipDocField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.tipDocField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public uint NrDoc
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nrDocField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nrDocField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType = "date")]
    public System.DateTime DataDoc
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dataDocField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dataDocField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType = "date")]
    public System.DateTime DataIntr
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dataIntrField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dataIntrField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public int NrIntr
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nrIntrField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nrIntrField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public int Retur
    {
        get
        {
            return this.returField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.returField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string DataAnulare
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dataAnulareField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dataAnulareField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string CodFurnizor
    {
        get
        {
            return this.codFurnizorField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.codFurnizorField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string DenFurnizor
    {
        get
        {
            return this.denFurnizorField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.denFurnizorField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal ValoareFaraTVA
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valoareFaraTVAField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valoareFaraTVAField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal ValoareTVA
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valoareTVAField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valoareTVAField = value;
        }
    }
}


}
```

And this is my method to get xml into an object:

```
 public static void fileCapIntr(string xmlFile) {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(IntrCap));
        IntrCap i;
        using (Stream reader = new FileStream(xmlFile, FileMode.Open))
        {
            // Call the Deserialize method to restore the object's state.
            i = (IntrCap)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }


    }
```

Any help please?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please show us the xml document

Comment: The very first "code" section in my post is the XML doc

Comment: @STF I rolled back your edit because the position mentioned in the error message would not make sense when the xml is formatted differently

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer, But like this you can see if there is a problem in the xml file - that happens lots of times

Comment: @STF I agree, that normally it would be a good idea to properly indent xml, but in this case it would have been obstructive. Don't let that discourage you from formatting questions but please always consider the context.

Comment: Can someone help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72265860/invaliddatacontractexception-type-cannot-be-serialized-consider-marking-it-wit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error

> There is an error in XML document (1, 64).

has an `InnerException` that reads:

> <root xmlns=''> was not expected.

Simple fix: Specify the `ElementName` of root:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(
    Namespace = "", 
    IsNullable = false, 
    ElementName = "root"
 )]
```

or specify it when creating the serializer

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(
    typeof(IntrCap), 
    null, 
    null, 
    new XmlRootAttribute("root"),
    ""
);
```

[Proof as dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tQdptu)

Comment: What about having a dinamically xml file, i mean dinamically number of roots?

Comment: You can't have multiple roots (actual **roots**, not elements named `root`). If you have multiple `root` elements, they need to be enclosed in another element, e.g. `roots`. In that case you can specify the name of the elements by defining `XmlArray` and `XmlArrayItem` attributes on a collection or creating an `XmlSerializer` with `typeof(List<IntrCap>)`, but that would depend on what **exactly** your xml looks like. If everything else fails, you can always manually parse your xml with `XmlReader` or `XmlDocument`.

Comment: What about this error at (1,292) at the following XML : https://jsfiddle.net/ufcd879u/1/

Comment: Why did you delete the other question?

Comment: I resolved it , and everybody rates me with a "minus"  :)